# Mark High/Low of 2nd 5min candle from market open

Tags: pine-script

Is there anyway to get the high and low value of the 2nd 5min candle from market open also target lines of 1:2 i.e
If 2nd candle is green,Target= high + 2*(high -low)
If 2nd candle is red, Target= Low - 2*(high-low)

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you've tried so far? What timeframe you chart is?

Comment: Timeframe is 5min